# Add Gutenberg editor to edit taxonomy (category) page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, block-editor

I have created a custom post type and custom taxonomy. I need to allow editing a taxonomy page in Gutenberg, but WordPress allows me to use only certain fields. How can I overcome this problem?

```
function first_post_type()
{

    $args = array(

        'labels' => array(

            'name' => 'Stock',
            'singular_name' => 'Unit',
        ),


        'hierachical' => true, 
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-schedule',
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
        //'rewrite' => array ('slug' => 'products'),
    );

    register_post_type('products', $args);

}
add_action('init', 'first_post_type');



function first_post_taxonomy()
{
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Categories',
                'singular_name' => 'Category',  
        ),
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true, 
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'show_in_rest'      => true,
            'query_var'         => true,            
    );

    register_taxonomy('units', array('products'), $args);

}

add_action('init', 'first_post_taxonomy');
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not add `show in rest` argument, set to true in post registration. Everything must be REST-enabled, since REST is the way block editor communicates with the rest :) of WordPress

Comment: Did you try this solution?